# Changing the volume without a volume slider on an iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, avfoundation

I need your help. How should I proceed to change the sound volume in my app. I don't want to use a volume slider. Instead I have an UIImageView which is a volume knob, in which I rotate clockwise to increase, and anti clockwise to decrease the sound volume. The rotation is just an animation and I've already done that part.

I need your help and advice on how to increase/decrease the volume. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would be careful calling `setValue` on an `MPVolumeView` since it probably won't do anything other than update the *appearance* of the slider, but not the actual device volume level.  You would instead have to call `_commitVolumeChange` which is private API and will likely get your app rejected.

A short answer to how to control volume:  It really depends on what you're trying to control the volume of.

If you want a "controls every sound within the app" sort of control then you can use an `MPVolumeView` but you **cannot** change it's value programmatically.  You would then only be able to change the volume by either moving the slider with a touch or using the volume buttons on the side of the device.  The best thing to do is create a global object that stores the volume level which any of your objects can read before they play their sound.

If it's an `AVAudioPlayer` object, you'd create the object and use `[theAudioPlayerObject setVolume: someFloat];` where `someFloat` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

If it's a `SystemSound` object, you can't control volume.

If it's an `AudioQueue` you'd change it via `AudioQueueSetParameter`

Like I said.. it all depends on *how* you are playing the sound.

**Update based on comment**

[For that particular example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html), you would set the volume like this:

> Add to the AudioStreamer.h file

```
- (void)setVolume:(float)Level;
```

> Add to the AudioStreamer.m file

```
- (void)setVolume:(float)Level
{

    OSStatus errorMsg = AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, Level);

    if (errorMsg) {
        NSLog(@"AudioQueueSetParameter returned %d when setting the volume.", errorMsg);
    }

}
```

> Add to the view controller for where the volume knob will be (this goes in the .m file.. i just did this as a couple UIButtons real quick, you'll have to do your own) and set up an IBAction to change the volume for a given value (you can pass in 0.0 thru 1.0 as a float)

```
- (IBAction)volumeUp:(id)sender
{

    [streamer setVolume:1.0];

}

- (IBAction)volumeDown:(id)sender
{

    [streamer setVolume:0.0];

}
```

Comment: I want to control the volume of my app. I'm trying to make an app using matt gallagher classes on how to stream an mp3 source http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Comment: Thank you very much rob, I will try it :D I'm quite new to iphone programming :D thanks :D

Comment: Not a problem, if you have issues implementing this, let me know and I'll post a sample project.  Try it on your own first, you'll learn more that way.

Comment: hey rob, is there a simple way to record what has been streamed with matt gallagher audio classes. I mean i want to record while playing simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry awics, you'd have to start a new question for that.  Stack Overflow is a one-question-per-post site so things stay organized for later readers looking for answers

Comment: okay rob :D could you help me please with this? :s I created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501227/record-simultaneously-while-streamer-is-playing

Comment: But what if you're using `AudioUnit` instead?

Answer (score 16):

I view this as a bug in Apple's code and have reported it to them both with Bug Reports and in person, but since they insist its a feature, you might as well benefit from it.

Use the following code to change your application's volume:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:newVolume];
```

This will only work after you have established your audio session, either by playing a sound or by setting it active as such:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL];
```

Note as that you'll need MediaPlayer.framework and AVFoundation.framework and that the volume is between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Simple and clear~~ :) Thanks a lot. Even if I don't use MPMusicPlayerController (e.g. using MPMoviePlayerController) I can use it. Due to AVAudioSession. :)

Comment: 'setVolume:' is deprecated in iOS 7.0

Answer (score 4):

Well, take the min Rotation (R1) and max Rotation (R2). Then do `rotation / (R2 - R1)` to get a % like a slider does.

EDIT:
To commit the volume change, add the following:

```
MPVolumeView *systemVolumeSlider = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
[systemVolumeSlider setHidden:YES];
[systemVolumeSlider setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.view addSubview:systemVolumeSlider];
```

(Make sure to release `systemVolumeSlider` in `dealloc`)

Then, when the volume is changed, use `setValue` to set its value. You will also need to handle what happens when your user presses volume +/- buttons on the device.

Comment: You might also want to tell them how to change the volume for a complete answer :)

Comment: thanks jrtc & iWasRobbed :D 
jrtc: lol my question was, after having the %, what's next, I'm stuck here xD

Comment: Yeah sure - I skimmed through your question and thought I had answered it, but hadn't quite! Answer has been updated though ;)

Comment: I would be careful using MPVolumeView... you cannot change the *volume* programmatically without calling `_commitVolumeChange` which is private API.

Comment: Apparently it automatically updates since iOS 3.0 - http://www.fraoula.com/?p=124

Comment: And you can also use `[MPMusicPlayerController setVolume:]`

Comment: Right, but keep in mind that's only if you use the volume control buttons on the side of the actual device.  Lemme put it this way: if it's not buried in the class reference, you probably can't do it using public api :)