# How to set volume in AudioQueue without the use of AudioQueueRef?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audioqueue

How to set volume in AudioQueue wthout the use of AudioQueueRef?

I have refered many question regarding this on Stack Overflow but all of them use AudioQueueRef object.

Is it possible to do so without use of AudioQueueRef?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an AudioQueueRef? That is simply a pointer to an Audio Queue object, so if you're using Audio Queues you have an AudioQueueRef somewhere.

Comment: @Hollance: Ok fine. I will try and create AudioQueueRef. I thought it is entirely  different object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458965/changing-the-volume-without-a-volume-slider-on-an-iphone). Though the question is different but you can use following code out of that ticked answer. Refer this below code in previous post.

```
OSStatus errorMsg = AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, Level);

    if (errorMsg) {
        NSLog(@"AudioQueueSetParameter returned %d when setting the volume.", errorMsg);
    }
```

for [above code refer to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)  **Controlling the Playback Level**

Also refer other answers too. Also I think MPVolumeView is working with AudioQueue so you can use that also.

Comment: Can you tell what `audioQueue` is? I think it is of type `AudioQueueRef` and I don't want to use AudioQueueRef Object.